# VBA - Show entire row on last item in drop down

Tags: vba, row, spreadsheet, dropdown

I am trying to unhide a row in my spreadsheet based on the value picked from a drop down list above.

I am not wanting to show this row based on a certain value, but only when anything other than the last row is selected.

So, for example, in a drop down list I have versions of Windows (with the last item being Windows 10). If the last item is selected, then the row below which would ask 'Is your version of Windows planned for an upgrade soon?' will stay hidden. Any other value will unhide this row.

This will help with future maintaining of the spreadsheet whereby when a new version of Windows is released, I can add this to the bottom of the drop down list, and the code will not need to be changed as it's looking for the last row for it's execution.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes it's possible, what have you tried?  Can you give more details of the dropdown, is it a combo, or cell validation?

Comment: Offcourse..It will be a bit tricky as there might other condition as well. Thanks

Comment: It's a combo box. So the cell is a drop down from data pulled from another sheet. Only thing I have tried thus far is writing the code to keep the row hidden if the cell = 'Windows 10'. I know it's only a small thing to amend when a new version comes out, but I want to keep this as automated as possible. Plus I have the same for Office/Exchange versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

To hide row depending on value in column above, in, lets say, cell A9 use event in Worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(external:=False) = "$A$9" And Target = "Windows 10" Then
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

You probably want to have last version of Wind not hardcoded however. But possible solution for this strongly depends on how you populate dropdown list.

Comment: Thanks for this. Ideally I don't want 'Windows 10' in the code as it's too much forward maintaining. The cell is a drop down populates from data in another sheet. So I just want the row to stay hidden unless anything other than the last item in that list is chosen.

EDIT: The last row being the latest version of Windows, for clarity.